# In Rails, using link_to is causing extra white space in my layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding a new `Delete` link at the end of a row. The code isn't using a table, but instead, is using a Bootstrap container and div's. When I add the word `Delete` to the end of the row, the row looks fine, but when I add this line instead,
`<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_conversation_path(conversation), method: :post %>*`,
all the columns in front get stuffed into column 1.

So my question is: How can I find out if `link_to` has default margins and/or padding?

Thank you!

Comment: "inspect element" in your browser's dev tools

Comment: `link_to` in simple words is rails wrapper to simple anchor tag `<a href='#'> text </a>`. Some `reset.css` like in bootstrap set margins and paddings to 0, so it is not rails specific problem, it is problem of CSS frameworks you use. Dev tools can help you investigating what's changing this margins, paddings.

Comment: Thank you! One of my major problems was that I was wrapping the link_to in a div and putting my class in that div rather than adding the class as a parameter to link_to.